# Aileron and elevator axes are swapped on the remote

Tags: servo

According to all resources I've found, this is not a remote mode issue - no modes have horizontal elevator and vertical aileron axes. My current setting is Mode 2.

Is it safe to swap the cables running from the aileron and elevator sockets on the helicopter?

(Probably just a result of me having plugged them into the wrong sockets after replacing the motherboard, but I don't want to brick another one)

Comment: AFAIK there should be no way to brick an RC RX by swapping the servo cables around, so you should be fine.

Comment: Usually, the servo cable/pin order either goes AETR or EATR, so there's a good chance you just have the first two swapped the wrong way for your RX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essentially all cases I can think of, you should have no problem with switching the servo/signal connections around on your RC RX. In fact, they're usually designed with that in mind.

What likely happened is that you misidentified the physical channel order of the servo/signal channels and have them plugged in the wrong order. This is quite common, as two of the most popular default channel orders are AETR and EATR. In fact, the only difference between them is the order of the aileron (*A*) and elevator (*E*) channels!